# What is a the correct way of expressing a (vote) majority?

Tags: political-theory, terminology

During the time, I have kept hearing about various expressions of a vote majority (TV discussions and titles, printed/on-line media etc.). The most common are [50% + 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority#.2250.25_.2B_1.22) and [51%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority#.2251.25.22). A [simple search](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2251%25%22) reveals that even some Politics.SE posts contain the second one.

However, Wikipedia mentions both of them as [erroneous definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority#Erroneous_definitions).

**Question:** **Is there a correct and short symbolic way to represent a majority?**

I am thinking about something like ">50%", but it does not seem to be used.

Comment: Whats wrong with the word majority? Its a short way (just one word!) to represent exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - There is nothing wrong with that word (although Wikipedia mentions some contexts where it means something different than "more than half"), but people want to avoid repeating themselves and use shorter or somehow catchier formulas. Also, "majority" is slightly longer than "50%+1" (depends on font) and might not fit within a large font breaking news title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a language question.

Comment: Context would mean everything here. I don't think there's a single answer here.

Comment: Just as an FYI, in the US, some states use `50% + 1` as their threshold for election. In multi-way races, if nobody reaches the threshold, there's a runoff election. I think Wikipedia's "erroneous" label only works in small data sets. For the electorate at large it seems to work just fine

Comment: @Machavity - yes, I think the same system is used in several (if not the majority) of European states. It's just that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority#.2250.25_.2B_1.22) mentions this way of expressing the majority as "erroneous" (due to possible rounding problems when the number of votes is odd).

Comment: @Alexei - The term is usually defined in the charter or constitution or what ever document it is that defines the rules of the vote.  It could be defined as simply the ballot item that gets the most votes, it could be 50%+1 it could be some other definition.

Comment: @Alexei I've never seen *50%+1* in a breaking news title or other headline.  Also, it's just as erroneous for larger data sets; it's only far less probable that it would matter.

Comment: This seems like it would be a better fit for English.SE (from the language perspective), or Maths.SE (for a stricter definition of a majority)

Comment: @SamuelMacleod it might also fit in those places, but it's also on topic here.  The definition of *majority* is central to political process.

Comment: @Alexei can you give an example of a European country that defines *majority* as 50% + 1?

Comment: @Machavity can you give an example of a US state that uses 50% + 1 as the definition of majority?

Comment: @phoog - in my native land (Romania), most of the Parliament's decisions require what is called a "(simple) majority" which translates to "> 50%" (of course, the quorum must be met). This is opposed some special decisions like changing the Constitution or accusing the President of high treason which require "> 2/3".

Comment: @Alexei but that's the point of this question: *50% + 1* is not the same as *>50%.*  The formulas give the same results for even numbers of votes, but not for odd numbers.  So people who characterize *majority* as meaning *50% + 1* are wrong unless the body in question explicitly defines it that way.  I thought you were saying that some European states *do* define it as *50% + 1,* but maybe I misunderstood.  (We also have the term *simple majority* in English.)

Comment: @phoog - The question was born out of the fact that Wikipedia mentions both popular ways of expressing simple majority as being wrong. I do not know if some states define it as `50%+1`.

Comment: 50%+ seems to be the shortest way to avoid incorrectly saying 51%

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because the notion that defining "majority" is off topic for [Politics.SE] is preposterous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *>50%* may not be used, it *should* be used, because that's what *majority* means.  Another way of expressing this is *more than half.*

As [David Grinberg](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/5407/david-grinberg) notes, however, it should [not be necessary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/what-is-a-the-correct-way-of-expressing-a-vote-majority/16906?noredirect=1#comment62105_16902) to define majority because it is [a well defined term](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/what-is-a-the-correct-way-of-expressing-a-vote-majority/16906?noredirect=1#comment62154_16906).  This explains why most documents, such as [the US Constitution](http://constitutionus.com/), do not define it.

The erroneous definitions obviously arise from a desire to underscore the fact that exactly 50% is not a majority.  This contrasts with most supermajority requirements, where the threshold is usually *at least.*  A more precise way to stress this fact would probably be to include a sentence noting that an evenly divided vote, or a proportion of exactly half, does not constitute a majority.

As implied in a [comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/what-is-a-the-correct-way-of-expressing-a-vote-majority#comment62117_16902), the problem is more likely to arise when the number of votes is small.  For example, if there are three votes, then the 50%+1 threshold arguably requires a unanimous vote, because 50%+1 of 3 is 2.5, and the only possible outcome greater than 2.5 is 3.

I have asked a related [question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18262/definition-of-majority) over at [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I mentioned this in a comment on the post, but I think its worth mentioning again. Why waste all this effort on finding new symbols for the word majority? Majority is a well defined word that... at the risk of sounding like an idiot... means exactly what we want. If you want to be clear _just use the word majority_.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg thanks, I have incorporated this into the answer.